# Как правильно зарегистрировать iAd?

Tags: ios, iphone, apple

Доброго времени суток.
Добавил iAd в приложение, оно работает и ид, и пт.
Но не получается зарегистрировать iAd в iTunes connect, так что бы шла настоящая реклама вместо тестовой страницы.
В разделе "Contracts, Tax, and Banking" заполнил всё по инструкции, но всё равно в приложении только тест рекламы.

Кто знает - скажите как правильно регистрировать iAd или скиньте ссылочку на подробное описание процесса.
У сам нагуглить инструкцию не смог.

Answer (score 1):

Настоящая реклама iAd появляется только в приложении, скачанном из App Store. Если в приложении появляется тестовая реклама, то всё работает и готово к отправке.