# IAd - как зарегистрировать в iTunesConnect

Tags: xcode, ios, objective-c

Был аналогичный вопрос: *[Как правильно зарегистрировать iAd?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/349436/ios-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-iad)*

На него ответа не дали. У меня в приложении стоит баннер, фреймворк, и т.д, вообщем программная часть сделана, банер вылазит тестовый. Что мне нужно зарегистрировать в iTunesConnect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот тут описывается:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343876/does-iad-integration-requires-any-registration-or-ad-setup

Заключение контракта.